# Filtering parameters in Rest API

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I have two entities 'persons' and 'businesses' and both of them have a sub-resource (e.g locations)

So I have endpoints:

```
GET /persons/{id}/locations
GET /businesses/{id}/locations
```

Now I want an endpoint to filter locations of a main resource.
If I do:

```
GET /persons/{id}/locations?country={...}
GET /businesses/{id}/locations?country={...}
```

I will search locations of a specific person/business.

What is the best practice to filter locations of all persons
I have some ideas:

```
1. GET /persons/locations?country={...}   
2. GET /locations?entity=persons&country={...}
```

But not sure these are fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the expand concept where you can be used with the relationship between the entities.

```
GET /persons

{
  "data": [
      {"person_id": 1},
      {"person_id": 2}
 ],
 "links": [ 
    {
        "rel": "locations",
        "href": "/person/1/locations"
    },
    {
        "rel": "locations",
        "href": "/person/2/locations"
    } 
  ]
}

GET /persons?expand=locations&country={...}   

{
  "data": [
      {"person_id": 1, "locations": [...]},
      {"person_id": 2, "locations": [...]}
  ]
}
```